# How to work with right-to-left languages for inline elements

Tags: html, css, right-to-left

I am trying to get a span with a url inside of it to behave as it would in left-to-right. This span has a surrounding container that has direction rtl on it, but I want to force this element to behave as left-to-right. For example:
http://jsfiddle.net/p6gab1zy/

```css
.rtl {
    direction: rtl;
}

.ltr {
    direction: ltr;
}
```

```html
<div class="rtl">
    <span class="ltr">http://www.google.com/</span>
</div>
```

In this fiddle, you can see that instead of displaying as `http://www.google.com/` it displays as `/http://www.google.com` because of the way that browsers put any symbols at the "end" of the text in right to left (being the left). If I put this span as `display: inline-block;` (http://jsfiddle.net/p6gab1zy/1/)

```css
.rtl {
    direction: rtl;
}

.ltr {
    direction: ltr;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="rtl">
    <span class="ltr">http://www.google.com/</span>
</div>
```

this will fix the issue, but unfortunately for my project this isn't an ideal solution. Does anyone have any other fixes that I can do that will work without having the possibility of shifting around the position of this element on the screen? By this I mean changing the display could move it up or down if padding/margin are on the element, so this isn't a viable solution for my needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CSS feature you are looking for is `unicode-bidi: bidi-override`. This creates a directional override on an inline-level element, so the language direction of the parent element will no longer stay in effect, so the end result will be what you're looking for.

If you apply this override to your `ltr` element, you can see that the text in that element will show up left-to-right normally. More information on `unicode-bidi` and overriding at [the MDN article here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unicode-bidi).

**Live Demo:**

```css
.rtl {
    direction: rtl;
}

.ltr {
    direction: ltr;
    unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
}
```

```html
<div class="rtl">
    <span class="ltr">http://www.google.com/</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Be very careful of using the bidi-override property, as it's meant to literally override the default behavior, which is *most usually* not what you want. For the most part, Unicode BiDi algorithm is sufficient in making these corrections automatically without requiring an override. In this case, for example, W3C recommends using 'dir' property instead of css rule, which (as you see from my answer below) fixes the situation without needing to override.

Answer (score 0):

You should actually use `dir="ltr"` and `dir="rtl"` rather than CSS classes; this is what W3C recommends as best practice. It makes sure elements use the wonderful Unicode Bidirectional Algorithm, which is quite good at making decisions on how to display these things in multiple language direction contexts.

Try this:

```
<div dir="rtl">בדיקה בעברית
  <span dir="ltr">http://www.google.com/</span>
</div>
```

(I added text in Hebrew to show that both directionalities work properly)

See the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mooeypoo/zrptysd6/).